# Separate log files for the same class using Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have printLog() method in Class C and these method is called from multiple classes say (Class A and Class B),I have print some logs from these printLog() method. I want to print these logs to different files based on the caller Class.

Case-1 : If call for printLog() is from Class A then logs should print to A.log file only

Case-2 : If call for printLog() is from Class B then logs should print to B.log file only

I have done the below configuration: log4j.xml

```
<category name="C">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="A.log" />
</category>

<category name="C">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="B.log" />
</category>
```

-But if log is of the level ERROR in printLog() then it prints in both log files irrespective to Caller class ie Class A or  Class B

[Please see attach image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItvGm.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have provided more details , please give feedback

Comment: Thank you for the addition, I hope your question will have more chance to get an answer with this addition. I'm not competent on the topic of your question, I was just reviewing its form.